# Make tools very janky (inconsistent across MSYS, Powershell, VSCode)

Tags: c, makefile

Attempting to use make, touch... When using `make` in MSYS, I receive the following error:

```
$ make
arm-none-eabi-gcc main.c  -W -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wundef -Wshadow -Wdouble-promotion -Wformat-truncation -fno-common -Wconversion -g3 -Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -I. -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16  -Tlink.ld -nostartfiles -nostdlib --specs nano.specs -lc -lgcc -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-Map=firmware.elf.map -o firmware.elf
make: arm-none-eabi-gcc: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:11: firmware.elf] Error 127
```

I can use `make` in powershell or VSCode terminal, however. Though, when I try to use touch in VSCode terminal or powershell, I get the following error.

```
touch main.c
touch : The term 'touch' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
```

I'm fairly new to everything so setting up environment variables has been messy. I'm trying to follow this guide https://github.com/cpq/bare-metal-programming-guide and it's been rocky. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I've tried editing shortening PATH directory lengths since I saw it mentioned as a point for strange behavior. That and most else of what I've tried has not helped.

Comment: `make` automates the running of commands.  But the commands it runs are, for the most part, executed in a shell running under an operating system, and different operating systems support different commands.  `touch` is standard on all Unix-like systems, but if it doesn't exist under Windows, you're kind of out of luck as far as using that particular Makefile is concerned.  (Perhaps you can use WSL?)

Comment: With that said, though, many uses of `touch` in Makefiles are ill-advised and/or unnecessary, so perhaps you can simply get rid of it.

Comment: The reality is that most stuff you'll find on GitHub, and free and open source software in general, is written for POSIX systems (such as GNU/Linux and, to some extent, MacOS).  Windows is a very, very different setup and it's much harder and more confusing to use with these F/OSS systems, with many options and different ways to do things that you generally have to figure out for yourself because the developers of the software Don't Do Windows.  If you want to use Windows as your development system, you're going to have to resign yourself to a steep learning curve just to get started.

Comment: And, when asking questions on StackOverflow, you should always include the info that "I'm using Windows" and then describe whatever toolkit/environment you're using (Cygwin?  MinGW?  WSL?  etc.)

Comment: Beginners should use IDEs as they automate and simplify the build process